# How to Calculate the difference between numbers in a Google sheet row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to calculate the difference of numbers that are inputted in a Google sheet row like this:

```
Row 1: 35 | 37 | 39 | 38 and So on...
```

I found a formula that can get the last entered number in Row 1:

```
=IFNA(LOOKUP(1, INDEX(1/(Row 1:1<>"")), Row 1:1),"")
```

However, I need to sum these values like this:

> **Row 1 Output: (37-35)+(39-37)+(38-39) = (2+2-1)=3**

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INDEX/COUNTA` to get the last column and `OFFSET` to shift the range by -1:

```
=LAMBDA(rg,SUMPRODUCT(rg-OFFSET(rg,0,-1)))(INDEX(1:1,2):INDEX(1:1,COUNTA(1:1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to following formula-

```
=SUM(INDEX(B1:INDEX(1:1,COUNTA(1:1))-A1:INDEX(1:1,COUNTA(1:1)-1)))
```

[image]

Comment: it works as expected when we add more values in the row1, when I delete column B, the formula then becomes: `=SUM(INDEX(#REF!:INDEX(1:1,COUNTA(1:1))-A1:INDEX(1:1,COUNTA(1:1)-1)`
and it gives #ref error, can we make it so that it auto-updates as the column deletes?

Comment: Why you are deleting column? Put formula after deleting column.

Comment: Because columns are added and deleted for the new updated values.

Answer (score 1):

```
Row 1 Output: (37-35)+(39-37)+(38-39) = (2+2-1)=3
```

Notice that the middle numbers (37 and 39) cancel out so you just need to subtract the first number from the last one

```
38-35 = 3
```

So this should be enough

```
=index(1:1,count(1:1))-A1
```

[image]