# Calculate Days between series of dates in a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I wanted to calculate the difference of numbers that are inputted in a Google sheet row like this:

```
Row 1: 35 | 37 | 39 | 38 and So on (until last non-empty cell)...

And the output would be:

Row 1 Output: (37-35)+(39-37)+(38-39) = (2+2-1)=3
```

the suggested formula for this calculation is:

```
=LAMBDA(rg,SUMPRODUCT(rg-OFFSET(rg,0,-1)))(INDEX(1:1,2):INDEX(1:1,COUNTA(1:1)))
```

Taking forward to this concept, now I want to calculate days between dates instead of numbers.

something like this (date format:yyy-mm-dd):

```
Row 1: (blank cell) | 2022-07-06 | (blank cell) | 2022-07-07 | 2022-07-08 and So on (until last non-empty cell)...
```

> **Expected Row 1 Output:(2022-07-07-2022-07-06)+(2022-07-08-2022-07-07) = (1+1)=2**

I used the above formula but I reckon formula is producing incorrect output because it does not exclude blank cells in between these dates, that's why it gives `44749` an an output,image is also attached:

[image: days issue]

Here is the how the table looks like in sample sheet in case you want to test it.

| Desired Output (No. of Days) | Date1 | Date2 | Date3 | Date4 | Date5 | Date6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2022-07-06 |  | 2022-07-07 | 2022-07-08 |  | 2022-07-09 |
| (G2-E2)+(E2-D2)+(D2-B2) |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 |  | 2022-07-06 |  |  |  | 2022-07-07 |
| (G4-C4) |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Table is starting from **column A to Column G**. Any guidance would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: 44748 is the numeric representation of 2022-07-06.  If you subtract the blank cell from 2022-07-06 then you are subtracting zero from 44748.  The answer will not be zero but rather 44748.  Then add 1 more for (2022-07-07) - (2022-07-06), to give your 44749.  I suggest you don't include that blank cell in your range.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, can we adjust such that if there is blank cell then it would leave that subtraction

Comment: You might be able to replace `rg-OFFSET(rg,0,-1)` with `IF(OFFSET(rg,0,-1)=0,0,rg-OFFSET(rg,0,-1))` (I haven't tried it) but I suspect there will still be some other issues with your formula like sumproduct instead of just sum and an off-by-one at the end of the range argument.

Comment: Hi there @EagleEye! Besides what Tony said, could you please clarify your formula? Split all the elements, like the `SUMPRODUCT`, on their own step for better legibility. Also please share an example Sheet.

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre]

Comment: [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73891921/)? If not, show how it's  different.

Comment: No it's different, the question you mentioned was series of numbers in a row without any blank spaces, while this question addresses to calculate the days from series of dates in a row with blank spaces between them, that's why the formula from that question would not work in this case

Comment: It's now last non-blank cell minus first non-blank cell so you could do it in a similar way to the way I did it previously https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73890549/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-numbers-in-a-google-sheet-row/73891921#73891921

Comment: that is not the case, we do have other dates between first and last non blank that need to be calculated, I tried your formula, it didn't work. your suggested formula: `=index(B2:2,count(B2:2))-B2` always subtracts B2, but if you look at the table, B4 cell is empty, date is starting from C4

Comment: That's right, it doesn't work because (a) you can't assume that the first date is in A1 and (b) you can't assume you can find the last date just by using count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways of finding the first and last non-blank cell in a row, but let's use xlookup for the sake of argument:

```
=ArrayFormula(xlookup(true,(B2:2<>""),B2:2,,0,-1)-xlookup(true,(B2:2<>""),B2:2,,0,+1))
```

[image]

But people just don't believe me when I tell them that (G2-E2)+(E2-D2)+(D2-B2) simplifies to G2-B2. It's basic algebra folks!

Or this is equivalent to my original formula but doesn't lend itself to being written as an array formula:

```
=index(filter(B2:2,B2:2<>""),count(B2:2))-index(filter(B2:2,B2:2<>""),1)
```

*EDIT*

Possible array formula (but could be a bit inefficient):

```
=iferror(byrow(B2:Z,lambda(r,index(filter(r,r<>""),count(r))-index(filter(r,r<>""),1))))
```

Also if dates are in ascending order left to right (or more exactly, if the first date is the smallest and the last date the largest), and because min and max ignore blanks, you can simplify the original formula to:

```
=max(B2:2)-min(B2:2)
```

or with byrow:

```
=ArrayFormula(byrow(B2:Z,lambda(r,if(min(r)=0,,max(r)-min(r)))))
```

Comment: I believe you, just a one more request, can we put it in array formula, so it runs for other rows as well instead of putting formula manually in every row i.e 3,4,5. thank you

Comment: Have to think about that one! I would probably go for a lambda now those are available.

Comment: I guess if the dates are in order from left to right you could also use minif and maxif to find the first and last in each row.